# Multi-threaded synchronous execution

Tags: multithreading, synchronous

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean),

> When you execute something synchronously, you wait for it to finish
> before moving on to another task

if this is the case, does multi-threaded synchronous execution means that other threads,say B,C,.. are waiting (blocked) for thread A to finish? if yes, then how can it differ from with single-threaded synchronous execution? what's the benefit?

**EDIT:**

In other words, does Multi-threaded Synchronous operation means :

```
thread A -> |----A-----|   
                        \  
thread B ------------>   ->|-----B-----------|   
                                              \   
thread C ---------------------------------->   ->|-------C------|
```

or it can be

```
thread A -> |----A-----|   
                         
thread B ->|-----B-----------|   
                                               
thread C ->|-------C------|
```

thanks.

Comment: nope. unless you use some synchronization object.

Answer (score 1):

No, other threads will just continue running. Only your current thread is blocked till the execution is finished. Normally you do this when you need the output for your next step.

Comment: ,if other threads continue running, can't we say that they are independent of thread A ,and then it would be asynchronous operations?